complex jolt transformation - inject into elements in an array
I have complex (EDI) input that looks like this:
{
  "INS-2000_loop": [
    {
      "INS_05": "A",
      "INS_06": "D",
      "INS_08": "AC"
    },
    {
      "REF_01": "0F",
      "REF_02": "111111111"
    },
    {
      "NM1-2100A_loop": [
        {
          "NM1_01": "IL",
          "NM1_02": "1",
          "NM1_03": "aaa",
          "NM1_04": "bbb"
        },
        {
          "PER_03": "HP",
          "PER_04": "1234567890"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "HD-2300_loop": [
        {
          "HD_01": "001",
          "HD_03": "HMO",
          "HD_04": "485-014-000",
          "HD_05": "IND"
        },
        {
          "DTP_01": "348",
          "DTP_02": "D8",
          "DTP_03": "20240401"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "HD-2300_loop": [
        {
          "HD_01": "001",
          "HD_03": "HMO",
          "HD_04": "485-014-000",
          "HD_05": "IND"
        },
        {
          "DTP_01": "348",
          "DTP_02": "D8",
          "DTP_03": "20240101"
        },
        {
          "DTP_01": "349",
          "DTP_02": "D8",
          "DTP_03": "20240331"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

The input can have any number of HD-2300_loop elements (typically less than 5) and only one INS-2000_loop element. I want the HD-2300_loop elements to "drive" the output so that output is an array of complex objects of the same length as the number of HD-2300_loop elements. The complex objects of the output array need to have all the data in the HD-2300_loop elements and the data of all the children of the INS-2000_loop element except the HD-2300_loop looking like this:
[
    {
        "L2300": [
            {
                "HD_01": "001",
                "HD_03": "HMO",
                "HD_04": "485-014-000",
                "HD_05": "IND"
            },
            {
                "DTP_01": "348",
                "DTP_02": "D8",
                "DTP_03": "20240101"
            },
            {
                "DTP_01": "349",
                "DTP_02": "D8",
                "DTP_03": "20240331"
            }
        ],
        "L2000": [
            {
                "INS_05": "A",
                "INS_06": "D",
                "INS_08": "AC"
            },
            {
                "REF_01": "0F",
                "REF_02": "111111111"
            },
            {
                "NM1-2100A_loop": [
                    {
                        "NM1_01": "IL",
                        "NM1_02": "1",
                        "NM1_03": "aaa",
                        "NM1_04": "bbb"
                    },
                    {
                        "PER_03": "HP",
                        "PER_04": "1234567890"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]

I've started with the following spec which isn't giving what I want - I haven't figured out how to inject the @3 selection into the result of the @1 selection. Also, I haven't figure out how to rename the selection results (to L2300 and L2000) and how to skip the HD-2300_loop child in the @3 selection result.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "HD-2300_loop": {
            "@1": "",
            "@3": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

I would also greatly appreciate if anyone could point me a Jolt doc or cheat sheet that explains how the & operators work. Thanks very much.

Also please add the code you have tried to your question. Remember this is a site to help people on specific coding problems, we are not here to do the code for you,

@TedLyngmo - this jolt spec will be used in Nifi - so not really a java issue

@JorgeCampos - yes, the code I've tried before is at the bottom of the original post. I know there's a lot more needed but that is the start I've made and getting stuck with the issues I describe in the last paragraph.

Sorry then. I saw the Java tag and was not seeing any code. I see now it is not a Java problem.

@AbhaiRajLlewellyn Ok, then use the [tag:apache-nifi] tag.

@TedLyngmo - it's not specifically a Nifi problem. Nifi just happens to be the environment I'm executing the code in. It'd be like tagging a regex question with python because I happen to be executing the regex in that env.

Well  that's actually how most regex questions are tagged because more often than not the context helps people answering.

@TedLyngmo regex maybe wasn't the best example because there are language-specific nuances to regex so it would make sense that people tag their regex questions with the language they're executing in. In this case though, the jolt spec has nothing to do with Nifi.

Could be, but it may help people to associate. Seeing you jolt snippet in the nifi context may spark thoughts like "that's not the idiomatic way to solve this with jolt in nifi".

Here's the final solution I came up with (includes some transformations not mentioned in the original problem):
[
    {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "INS-2000_loop": {
          "*": {
            "INS*": "L2000.&",
            "NM1-2100A_loop": {
              "*": {
                "D*|L*|N*": "L2000.L2100A.&",
                "PER_04": {
                  "@": "L2000.L2100A.PER[].value",
                  "@(1,PER_03)": "L2000.L2100A.PER[#2].type"
                },
                "PER_06": {
                  "@": "L2000.L2100A.PER[].value",
                  "@(1,PER_05)": "L2000.L2100A.PER[#2].type"
                },
                "PER_08": {
                  "@": "L2000.L2100A.PER[].value",
                  "@(1,PER_07)": "L2000.L2100A.PER[#2].type"
                }
              }
            },
            "NM1-2100G_loop": {
              "*": {
                "N*": "L2000.L2100G.&",
                "PER_04": {
                  "@": "L2000.L2100G.PER[].value",
                  "@(1,PER_03)": "L2000.L2100G.PER[#2].type"
                },
                "PER_06": {
                  "@": "L2000.L2100G.PER[].value",
                  "@(1,PER_05)": "L2000.L2100G.PER[#2].type"
                },
                "PER_08": {
                  "@": "L2000.L2100G.PER[].value",
                  "@(1,PER_07)": "L2000.L2100G.PER[#2].type"
                }
              }
            },
            "REF_01": {
              "*": {
                "@(2,REF_02)": "L2000.@(2)"
              }
            },
            "HD-2300_loop": {
              "*": {
                "HD*": "L2300s.[&3].L2300.&",
                "DTP_01": {
                  "*": {
                    "@(2,DTP_03)": "L2300s.[&5].L2300.@(2)"
                  }
                },
                "LX-2310_loop": {
                  "*": {
                    "N*": "L2300s.[&5].L2300.L2310.&",
                    "PER_04": {
                      "@": "L2300s.[&6].L2300.L2310.PER[].value",
                      "@(1,PER_03)": "L2300s.[&6].L2300.L2310.PER[#2].type"
                    },
                    "PER_06": {
                      "@": "L2300s.[&6].L2300.L2310.PER[].value",
                      "@(1,PER_05)": "L2300s.[&6].L2300.L2310.PER[#2].type"
                    },
                    "PER_08": {
                      "@": "L2300s.[&6].L2300.L2310.PER[].value",
                      "@(1,PER_07)": "L2300s.[&6].L2300.L2310.PER[#2].type"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "COB-2320_loop": {
                  "*": {
                    "COB*": "L2300s.[&5].L2300.L2320[&5].&",
                    "DTP_01": {
                      "*": {
                        "@(2,DTP_03)": "L2300s.[&7].L2300.L2320[&7].@(2)"
                      }
                    },
                    "NM1-2330_loop": {
                      "*": {
                        "N*": "L2300s.[&7].L2300.L2320[&7].L2330.&"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "L2000": "&",
        "L2300s": {
          "*": { "L2300": "L2300s[]" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "L2300s": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,L2000)": "[&].L2000",
            "@": "[&].L2300"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]


Hi this spec will help you resolve the query :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "INS-2000_loop": {
        "*": {
          "HD-2300_loop": {
            "*": "[#5].L2300"
          },
          "INS_*": "[#4].L2000.[#2].&",
          "REF_*": "[#4].L2000.[#2].&",
          "NM1-2100A_loop": "[#4].L2000.[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "L2300": {
          "*": {
            "key": "=concat(@(1,HD_01),@(1,HD_03),@(1,HD_04),@(1,HD_05),@(1,DTP_01),@(1,DTP_02),@(1,DTP_03))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "L2300": {
          "*": "test.@key[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[#2].&",
      "test": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#4].L2300.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "key": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Explaination:
As for am keeping the things as normal required list.
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "INS-2000_loop": {
        "*": {
          "HD-2300_loop": {
            "*": "[#5].L2300"
          },
          "INS_*": "[#4].L2000.[#2].&",
          "REF_*": "[#4].L2000.[#2].&",
          "NM1-2100A_loop": "[#4].L2000.[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }


In first operation:

From "HD-2300_loop" am taking all attributes and keeping them in new array "L2300" and rest fields in "L2000".
 {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "L2300": {
          "*": {
            "key": "=concat(@(1,HD_01),@(1,HD_03),@(1,HD_04),@(1,HD_05),@(1,DTP_01),@(1,DTP_02),@(1,DTP_03))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


In this operation am creatin a unique key based on attributes present in each L2300 object to eliminate duplicates.
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"": {
"": "&",
"L2300": {
"": "test.@key[]"
}
}
}
}, {
"operation": "cardinality",
"spec": {
"test": {
"": "ONE"
}
}
}

This 3 specs are used to remove dublicate attributes from the L2300 list.
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"": "[#2].&",
"test": {
"": {
"@": "[#4].L2300.[]"
}
}
}
}, {
"operation": "remove",
"spec": {
"": {
"": {
"*": {
"key": ""
}
}
}
}
}

Last 2 operations are to create required structure.


For Jolt Documentation of # and & you can explore Digibee documentations :
https://docs.digibee.com/documentation/components/tools/transformer-jolt/transformer-getting-to-know-jolt

Thanks very much @Arnold Joseph - for the help with the specs and especially for the link to documentation.

Great can you pls accept and upvote the answer too pls.
